# why change custom dependency property showcustombuton value not update in designer window in designer time

Tags: c#, wpf, window, custom-controls

all. Why change custom dependency property showcustombuton value not update in designer window in designer time.

I've tried a lot, with no results.

My expectation: When the value of ShowCustomButton is False, the Button in the designer should be hidden, and when the value of ShowCustomButton is True, the Button in the designer should be displayed. But modifying the value, the button doesn't change.
My code works as expected when I run the project。

I want it to work as expected at design time in the designer window.

App.xaml:

```
  <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="\Themes\Generic.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Generic.xaml:

```
 <ControlTemplate  x:Key="d" TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomWin}">
        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center"     Margin="0 10 0 0"   FontSize="22"   FontWeight="DemiBold"     Foreground="RoyalBlue"    Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"     Orientation="Horizontal"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"     VerticalAlignment="Center"    Margin="0 10 15 0">
                <Button x:Name="PART_CustomButton"     Content="Custom Button"  Width="100"     Margin="0 0 10 0"     />
                <Button Content="+"     Width="25"  Height="22"    Margin="0 0 10 0"/>
                <Button Content="X"     Width="25"    Height="22" />
            </StackPanel>
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style  TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomWin}" >
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="MintCream"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#0046E7"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource d}"/>
    </Style>
```

CustomWin :

```
[DesignTimeVisible(true)]
public class CustomWin : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowCustomButtonProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ShowCustomButton",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(CustomWin),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, OnShowCustomButtonChanged)
        );

    [Category("Appearance")]
    public bool ShowCustomButton
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowCustomButtonProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ShowCustomButtonProperty, value); }
    }

    private Button customButton;

    static CustomWin()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomWin), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomWin)));
    }


    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        customButton = GetTemplateChild("PART_CustomButton") as Button;
        UpdateCustomButtonVisibility();
    }

    private static void OnShowCustomButtonChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = (CustomWin)d;
        window.UpdateCustomButtonVisibility();
    }

    private void UpdateCustomButtonVisibility()
    {
        if (customButton != null)
        {
            customButton.Visibility = ShowCustomButton ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<local:CustomWin x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" Template="{StaticResource d }" ShowCustomButton="False"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</local:CustomWin>

   public partial class MainWindow : CustomWin
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

The result:

[image]

**Update:**

```
<local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>

 <Button x:Name="PART_CustomButton"     Content="Custom Button"  Width="100"     Margin="0 0 10 0"
                         Visibility="{Binding ShowCustomButton, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

BoolToVisibilityConverter :

```
   public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        private object GetVisibility(object value)
        {
            if (!(value is bool))
                return Visibility.Hidden;
            bool objValue = (bool)value;
            if (objValue)
            {
                return Visibility.Hidden;
            }
            else
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
        public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return GetVisibility(value);
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

CustomWin :

```
 [DesignTimeVisible(true)]
    public class CustomWin : Window
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowCustomButtonProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "ShowCustomButton",
                typeof(bool),
                typeof(CustomWin),
                new PropertyMetadata(false)
            );

        [Category("Appearance")]
        public bool ShowCustomButton
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowCustomButtonProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ShowCustomButtonProperty, value); }
        }

    
        static CustomWin()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomWin), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomWin)));
        }
}
```

Comment: As a note, a DependencyObject does not need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Dependency properties already provide their own change notification mechanism.

Comment: yes， its the code i tried trying to get it to work at design time, now i updated。

Comment: Instead of a PropertyChangedCallback that accesses an element in the Template (which may or may not exist), you could add a Trigger on the ShowCustomButton property to the ControlTemplate.

Comment: Please see the update in my question, it works at runtime and not at design time.

Comment: Visibility is only changed at runtime as far as i know. You can change the property 'visible' to false in the designer itself and the item will still be visible. Why would you want to hide something in design mode? I dont really see the use-case for that. However maybe wrap the button in a custom control and only load it at runtime. This way it will stay hidden.

Comment: Just another note, the logic in your BoolToVisibilityConverter is reverted. Besides that, you don't need to write that converter yourself. There is one in the framework.

Comment: It does work at runtime, and I want it to work at design time as well. Is there a way to do it? Or is there a reason why it can't be done?